# scala collect always returns Array of type Any

Tags: arrays, scala, casting, any, collect

I am trying to run collect on a dataframe and then perform operations on the elements of the resultant Array.

```
scala> scans.withColumn("src_port_list", udf((x: Seq[Int]) => x.distinct).apply($"src_port_list")).select("src_port_list").collect().map(_(0))
res29: Array[Any] = Array(WrappedArray(38897, 35378, 32947, 24280, 33181, 24782, 40937, 20824, 39685, 39841, 40191, 39031, 40981, 40919, 24436, 39765, 39784, 39881, 41037, 41079, 38874, 39916, 39788, 40468, 40041, 40941, 39325, 38902, 38896, 36151, 41061, 41016, 38921, 39269, 24437, 39001, 24282, 38923, 38920, 39835, 38901, 37585, 38922, 40977, 38898, 39862, 40926, 39909, 38743, 39774, 39761, 40918), WrappedArray(50974, 50998, 51947, 51428, 51012, 50996, 50984, 51564, 51037, 51045, 50980, 51027, 51010, 51036, 51030, 51025, 50992, 50983, 50993, 51009, 50991, 50989, 50990, 51011, 51031, 50987, 50986, 50985, 51028, 51041, 51001, 51035, 51029, 51026, 50995, 50976, 50997, 50981, 50994, 50988, 50975), WrappedArray(53148, 52396, 52318, 52422, 52420, 53064, 52394, 52329, 53156, 53072, 53126, 53...
```

I need to cast the WrappedArrays inside the resultant Array to sets so that I can perform union / intersection operations, but because they are being treated as type Any, I cannot perform any of the casting operations.

Comment: `_(0)`  returns an **Any**. Maybe you want `_.getAsInt(0)`?

Comment: @LuisMiguelMejíaSuárez I think here it should be `_.getAs[Array[Int]](0)`

Comment: @BorisAzanov ah I didn't see it was nested array. Then it should be `_.getSeq[Int](0)`

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out as I was posting the question:

Need to import scala.collection.mutable.WrappedArray and use .asInstanceOf[WrappedArray[Int]]

Comment: Using `asInstanceOf` is a bad practise in scala, better to get specific type of something using pattern matching or methods with generic type parameters which returns type what you need. For example `org.apache.spark.sql.Row.getAs[T](n: Int)`

Comment: @BorisAzanov usually I would agree, but `getAs` is just a good name for an `asInstanceOf`.

Comment: @LuisMiguelMejíaSuárez yeah you are right, then it's a bad choice also

Comment: @BorisAzanov well you actually don't have an alternative, that is the way **Spark** was designed. The SQL module is untyped, period. The alternative is to use `Datasets` instead, but then again, it won't tell you something is wrong until runtime, you may just make the check as soon as possible to avoid wasting computing time.